# Argparse of a JSON that is inside a string

Tags: python, json, argparse

Trying to pass a **string that contains a JSON to argparse**, can not use what is produced as a proper JSON (**json.loads Error**), need help!
That is what I have tried

```
import argparse
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', dest='parametros', nargs='+', type=str,
                   help='dados')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.parametros)
```

Now, I'm using:

```
python test.py b'-a field1=\'pokemonmaster\' -a field2=\'{"_id": {"$oid": "5de"}, "code": 2, "field1": "pokemonmaster", "filter": "name", "descricao": "Circunst\\u00e2ncia", "data": null, "status": "1001"}\''
```

output is a type list:

```
["field2='{_id:", '{:', '5de},', 'code:', '2,', 'field1:', 'pokemonmaster,', 'filter:', 'name,', 'descricao:', 'Circunst\\u00e2ncia,', 'data:', 'null,', 'status:', "1001}'"]
```

The closest I got from the desired JSON-like string was after

```
aux1 = ' '.join(args.parametros)
aux2 =  aux1.split("field2=")
aux3 = ''.join(aux2)
aux4 = aux3.split('\'')
print(aux4[1])
```

and the output is a type str:

```
{_id: {: 5de}, code: 2, field1: pokemonmaster, filter: name, descricao: Circunst\u00e2ncia, data: null, status: 201}
```

What I need is :

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "5de"}, "code": 2, "field1": "pokemonmaster", "filter": "name", "descricao": "Circunst\\u00e2ncia", "data": null, "status": "1001"}
```

**Problems:**

**1)**  Somehow argparse is not detecting the keys with $ dollar sign, e.g.: {"$oid": "5de"} -> {:', '5de}

**2)** If json.loads(aux4[1]) is tried, this is the result

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

**3)** Is there a way to add the quotations marks properly in the output?

Comment: Afaict The field2 end delimiter is different from the start delimiter, is thatcorrect?

Comment: What is the purpose of the leading `b` in your first command `python test.py b'-a ...'`?  It looks like you're expecting it to be a bytestring.

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around all the -a value.

Comment: I haven't tried to understand you example yet.  But 1) with enough quoting you can pass a valid `json` string as a commandline value (when in doubt check the `sys.avgv`), 2) you can parse the string with `json.loads`, even specifying it as an argument `type` function.

Comment: Your shell quoting looks wrong to me.  (Why you you start with `b`?  Why are your `-a` parameters inside of a single string?)  Additionally, `field1` and `field2` are confusing to me.  If they need to be dynamic, just make them part of the JSON (they currently don't use the correct syntax).  If they are static, then change your `ArgumentParser` to take `--field1` and `--field2` separately.  Part of the problems seems to be that you are trying to do too many different things at once.

Comment: I just updated the question, hopefully adding more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your json is malformed.

Try to use the Hjson Lib:

https://hjson.github.io/

```
import hjson

 ...

hjson.loads(yourText);
```

Comment: demjson Lib also does that